# Summing values up to a column value change in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
            Count  Status
Date                                                                       
2021-01-01  11     1
2021-01-02  13     1
2021-01-03  14     1
2021-01-04  8      0
2021-01-05  8      0
2021-01-06  5      0
2021-01-07  2      0
2021-01-08  6      1
2021-01-09  8      1
2021-01-10  10     0
```

I want to calculate the difference between the initial and final value of the "Count" column before the "Status" column changes from 0 to 1 or vice-versa (for every cycle) and make a new dataframe out of these values.

The output for this example would be:

```
Cycle  Difference
1       3
2      -6
3       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) by consecutive groups created by comapre shifted values with cumulative sum, last subtract last and first value:

```
df = (df.groupby(df['Status'].ne(df['Status'].shift()).cumsum().rename('Cycle'))['Count']
        .agg(['first','last'])
        .eval('last - first')
        .reset_index(name='Difference'))
print (df)
   Cycle  Difference
0      1           3
1      2          -6
2      3           2
3      4           0
```

If need filter out groups rows with 1 row is possible add aggregation [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and then filter oupt rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(df['Status'].ne(df['Status'].shift()).cumsum().rename('Cycle'))['Count']
        .agg(['first','last', 'size'])
        .loc[lambda x: x['size'] > 1]
        .eval('last - first')
        .reset_index(name='Difference'))
print (df)
   Cycle  Difference
0      1           3
1      2          -6
2      3           2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) on the groups formed of the consecutive values, then get the first minus last value (see below for variants):

```
out = (df.groupby(df['Status'].ne(df['Status'].shift()).cumsum())
         ['Count'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0])
       )
```

output:

```
Status
1    3
2   -6
3    2
4    0
Name: Count, dtype: int64
```

If you only want to do this for groups of more than one element:

```
out = (df.groupby(df['Status'].ne(df['Status'].shift()).cumsum())
         ['Count'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0] if len(x)>1 else pd.NA)
         .dropna()
       )
```

output:

```
Status
1     3
2    -6
3     2
Name: Count, dtype: object
```

##### output as DataFrame:

add `.rename_axis('Cycle').reset_index(name='Difference')`:

```
out = (df.groupby(df['Status'].ne(df['Status'].shift()).cumsum())
         ['Count'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0] if len(x)>1 else pd.NA)
         .dropna()
         .rename_axis('Cycle').reset_index(name='Difference')
       )
```

output:

```
   Cycle Difference
0      1          3
1      2         -6
2      3          2
```